# Does the Hölder coefficient tend to zero?

Tags: uniform-convergence, holder-spaces

A continuous fucntion $f: \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with $\Omega$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, is a $\alpha$-Hölder continuous with $0< \alpha\leq 1$, if
\begin{equation}
[f]_{\alpha}:=\sup_{x,y\in \Omega, x\ne y} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}<\infty.
\end{equation}

Here is my problem. If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of $\alpha$-Hölder continuous function on a compact subset $\Omega$,and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\Omega$, that is, $\lim_n\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}=0$. If $f$ is also $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, is it true that $\lim_n[f_n-f]_{\alpha}=0$?

Here is my analysis. According to the definition, we have
\begin{align*}
[f_n-f]_{\alpha}&=\sup_{x,y\in \Omega, x\ne y}\frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)-f_n(y)+f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\\
&=\sup_{x,y\in \Omega, x\ne y}\frac{|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f_n(y)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\\
&\leq \sup_{x,y\in \Omega, x\ne y}\frac{2\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

It seems to me that the analysis is okay, but I need a double check in case there is some missing points.

Comment: Not correct. $\sup_{x,y\in \Omega, x\ne y}\frac{2\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} =\infty$ for each $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Since $\lim_n\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}=0$, is it true that $\sup_{x,y\in \Omega, x\ne y}\frac{\|f_n-f\|_{\infty}}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}=\infty$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @RebecaJ: Yes, because you're first taking the supremum over $x,y$, and then the limit in $n$.

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks a lot.

Comment: Think about the functions $n^a \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^b}\right),$ for positive constants $a,b$, and $\Omega=(0,1)$.

Comment: It seems that I did not explain it clearly, $\Omega$ should be a compact suebset. Is there any case that $\lim_n[f_n-f]=0$?

Comment: You can take $\Omega=[0, 1]$ as well in those examples.

Comment: @Jose27 I considered $f_n(x)=n\sin(\frac{x}{n})$ on $\Omega=[0,1]$. Then, $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f(x)=x$. But I could not figure out what happens to $\lim_n[f_n-f]$, could you please give some details?